# what is the best push service for android?

Tags: android, service, push

What is the best push service for android?

And what is the easiest to use?

I have already tried the GCM for push service, but i think it's difficult to applied. I want to use the push service without google account.

Thankyou

Comment: The best one is GCM, since it's a part of Android and you can assume it's already running on people's Android devices and you can already assume that your users have a google account (since they're using Android). Whatever push service you can use, it will still require a unique identifier (for instance like an SMS phone number), or something extra to be installed on the user's device and that therefore will use a lot of power (at least 10% of the device's power each day if I remember correctly). Also, keep in mind that some services piggy back on GCM and can make it easier to use.

Comment: Although, those piggy back services still require the user to have a Google account since they're just using GCM underneath.

Answer (score 2):

GCM is the best and its quite easy:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

The simplest implementation is a receiver class, a registering code and a HTTPS query serverside:

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => array("ClientID"),
    'data' => array("message" => "OK")
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=APIKey',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) die('cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);
print_r(json_decode($result));
```

You can register the API key at https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/

For the clientside implementation have a look at the link on top.

GCM is also vey good because every Android smartphone has a permanent connection to Google and that means that it doesn't drain any battery when you use it too. If you want to use another one you are draining additional battery.

If you have a specific question feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://parse.com

That one is definitely the easiest, you can download their demo code and everything works like it's been prewired. I haven't used Parse in a while (so I don't know if it relies on GCM, but if they're smart it should).

Then, there is http://stackmob.com

Personally, I'd just stick to GCM if I were you (unless you're doing a hackathon or something).

Comment: Is there ant other framework available which servers better than parse in free ?